# Problem With Redmine SHA1 Password Confirmation (Kotlin & Java)

Tags: java, redmine, sha1

I want to generate Redmine User Password for password confirmation from an Android App with Java . In Redmine the password is stored as :

```
> The hashed password is stored in the following form: SHA1(salt + SHA1(password))
```

According to this information I tried the following code block:

```
public  String encryptPassword(String password)
    {
        String sha1 = "";
        try
        {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sha1;
    }

public  String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
{
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    String result = formatter.toString();
    formatter.close();
    return result;
}
```

For the password string "test" in Redmine db, I have the salt `90dda74a652abf68cc30f18491e9710a` and hashed password `0daf7c133e097573920fe9fadbb3a79bb279613d`.

With the code that I wrote above I tried:

```
        val shaPassObj = Sha1Generator()
        val shaPass = shaPassObj.encryptPassword("test")

        val shaPass2=shaPassObj.encryptPassword("90dda74a652abf68cc30f18491e9710a$shaPass")
        print(shaPass2)
```

And I obtained `20fc92fc1b60e6254a35e080d53e0e5039e3f1ac` that is not matched with the hashed password above. So What am I doing wrong ? Or does the hashing form of Redmine is different from SHA1(salt + SHA1(password)) ?

Comment: I am not sure, what you're doing wrong here, but the hashing function `encryptPassword` already yields different results. `User.hash_password('test')` on my machine returns `"a94a8fe5ccb19b..."` instead of `"0daf7c133e09..."`.

So the overall approach of SHA1(salt + SHA1(password)) is not at fault here. It's how you're computing the SHA1 hashes.

Comment: @GregorSchmidt the value 0daf7c133e097573920fe9fadbb3a79bb279613d is coming from redmine database. I also obtain the value a94a8fe5ccb19b... with my code but my goal is to obtain the same value that is coming from Redmine database

Comment: I am sorry. I misread that part of your question. I've just tested your salt in combination with `"test"` with the current Redmine code base. Redmine also yields `20fc92fc1...`, just like your Java code. The Redmine code was last updated in 2011, when the salting was added. Unfortunately, I have no idea, why your database contains a different `hashed_password`.